# Localization of custom Azure Pipelines build tasks

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am working on creating a custom task for Azure Pipelines and would like to know more and support localization. Please help out if localization of Azure Pipelines custom build tasks is supported by providing additional JSON files for each locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I failed to find the instructions in the official docs, but this is what I can see on Github for Microsoft Azure Pipelines tasks. Not sure it will work without some custom magic, but it's worth trying at least.

Let's take [PowerShell task](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/PowerShellV2) as an example:

- there's a file called `task.loc.json`, which contains placeholders instead of translatable phrases, like this: `"description": "ms-resource:loc.description"`
- then, there's a folder [`/Strings/resources.resjson`](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/PowerShellV2/Strings/resources.resjson), full of subfolders, one per particular culture
- each culture subfolder contans a [`resources.resjson`](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/PowerShellV2/Strings/resources.resjson/ru-RU/resources.resjson) file with translations tied to those placeholders, e.g. `"loc.description": "Выполнение скрипта PowerShell в Windows, macOS или Linux."`

This looks like a convention. There might be some magic hidden in the build scripts to make it work, but I failed to find it at first glance.

Comment: that gives me something to start on, I really need that additional custom magic if any to get it together and working. I wanted to know if any modifications needs to be done on the vss-extension.json

Comment: @vCillusion Have you tried just following the convention to see if it works?

Comment: I given it a try, and added folder for de-de and relevant resources, I modified the country and region from my profile to Germany and Deutchland
My bad, I am not able to view it in the UI in the de resources